# ref on a slot element in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

In aurelia, when using slots in a custom element, is it possible to use the ref element on a slot somehow (maybe new feature for Aurelia team?, the github issue thingy said to post on SO instead of on github).

Example:

element.html:

```
<template> 
    My super awesome element
    <slot ref="slotContent"></slot>
</template>
```

element.ts

```
export class CollapsePanel
{
    private slotContent: Element;

    attached(): void
    {
        this.slotContent.classList.add("my-fancy-class");
    }
}
```

otherview.html

```
<element>
    <div>This is some element content!</div>
</element>
```

rendered otherview.html

```
<element>
    My super awesome element
    <div class="my-fancy-class">This is some element content!</div>
</element>
```

Is there any way to do this currently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would force the user of your component to use a html element that can have a class property. Would it be better to do something like this:

Template for custom element

```
<template>
  <div ref="slotContent"><slot></slot></div>
</template>
```

Code:

```
export class CustomElement
{
    private slotContent: HTMLDivElement;

    attached(): void
    {
        this.slotContent.classList.add("my-fancy-class");
    }
}
```

With the custom element (with a textnode instead of a html element)

```
<customElement>foo</customElement>
```

Comment: Hi Erik, do you think you could help me with this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978120/how-can-i-configure-two-or-more-apps-in-aurelia-using-webpack